# What is the proper way to make a destructor for this binary node class?

Tags: c++, tree, binary-tree, destructor

```
class node{

private:
node* parent;
node* leftchild;
node* rightchild;
// etc.... 
}
```

I don't want to create  an infinite cycle with destructor that's why I'm interested how can I make a good  constructor for it.

Comment: There is no proper way. It is for you to decide what the node class is responsible and who owns the children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `delete` on a pointer that is `NULL` will not call the destructor.
Just set the nodes to `NULL` in constructor, and only allocate them if they are supposed to exist.

So its safe to delete the sub-objects in the destructor, cause the 'chain' will stop when it reaches a child-node that is `NULL`.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

class Node{
public:
  Node() {
    node = NULL;
  }
  ~Node() {
    std::cout << "Deleting" << std::endl;
    delete node;
  }
  void CreateChildNode() {
    node = new Node();
  }
private:
  Node* node;
};

int main()
{
  Node *n = new Node();
  n->CreateChildNode();
  delete n;
  return 0;
}
```

Above code snippet will output:
*Deleting

Deleting*

Comment: Calling `delete` on a pointer that has not been initialized is undefined behavior. You must always initialize pointers with the address of an object or with NULL (calling `delete` on a NULL pointer is safe and does nothing). The only exception are global variables of pointer type because they are automatically initialized to NULL when the program starts.

Comment: and does the  order of deleting the parent, left and right matters?

Comment: You don't have to delete the parent, cause the parent's deletion is the reason that the children are deleted. Left/Right does not matter no.

Comment: Happy to help. Please mark answer as correct if it was the correct answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would say:

```
node::~node()
{
    // remove reference to this from neighboor.
    if (leftchild) {
        leftchild->parent = nullptr;
    }
    if (rightchild) {
        rightchild->parent = nullptr;
    }
    if (parent) {
        if (parent->leftchild == this) {
            parent->leftchild = nullptr;
        } else {
            parent->rightchild = nullptr;
        }
    }
}
```

And the correct smartPointer (`std::shared_ptr`/`std::weak_ptr` or pointer/`std::unique_ptr`) for `parent`/( `leftchild`, `rightchild`).